# Breaking the line into small segments

Tags: postgis, point, spatialite, select, linestring

I am using spatialite and it does not contains the method ST_dumppoints and ST_dump. I want to divide several linestring into smaller parts. I also have points that I combined and that resulted in a linestrings. Now I want to divide these linestring into several parts.

I have tried using ST_line_substring and ST_line_locate_point but nothing is working.

Is there a way to divide linestring into smaller segments say 100m in spatialite?

What I have done is:

```
select 
ASText(ST_Line_Substring(linearea.geometry,0,
ST_Line_Locate_Point(linearea.geometry, Transform(setsrid(pointarea.geometry,4326),3857))))  AS Geometry
from LineArea linearea,PointArea pointarea

PontArea is Area which I combined to make LineArea using MakeLine(ST_point(long,lat))
```

Comment: There is a function for that in https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html.

Comment: @user30184 for what?

Comment: Are you talking about ST_segmentize well I have used it. it is not working

Comment: Wait, do you want more vertices to your lines or really cut them so that you will have many short linestrings? Segment is what you have between two vertices. ST_Segmantize is adding vertices and makes shorter segments but it feels like you are not satisfied with small segments really.

Comment: @user30184 I just to cut them so that small linestrings are made of one large linestring

Comment: Yes you are right I want to make small linestrings from one large linestring by cutting them in pieces

Comment: I believe you can do it by using Line_Interpolate_Equidistant_Points first and performing then LinesCutAtNodes with the MultiPoint from the previous step. Test carefully, it may happen that some points do not split the geometries.

Comment: @user30184 Okay I am trying

Comment: @user30184 I have tried but it is really slow and make huge amount of linestrings from single large linestring

Comment: It is not working with Line_Interpolate_Equidistant_Points but only working with Line_Interpolate_Points which is very very slow and gives almost 50 lines for one large linestring.

Comment: Please do not tell so often that something does not work while it is probably as usual that we do not yet know how to do it right. Line_Interpolate_Equidistant_Points does not really work as easily as I thought because LinesCutAtNodes requires that lines really have vertices at cutting points so they should be added first.

Comment: @user30184 okay, So is there any other way?

Comment: Something based on ST_Line_Substring should work. As an example the first 100 unit long part of one WKT linestring `select st_line_substring(st_geomfromtext('linestring (0 0, 100 100)'),0,100/st_length(st_geomfromtext('linestring (0 0, 100 100)')))`. More SQL is needed for selecting the next parts.

Comment: The problem is that I could only select the first 10 or say 20 percent of linestring and I dont have anything that get me the remaining part

Comment: ST_line_substring takes both start and end distances. The second part starts where the first part ends. It is for sure possible but the SQL will get rather complicated. I apologize but the complete solution feels too broad for this forum.

Answer (score 2):

I would point you to using the [`ST_Line_Substring`](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_Line_Substring.html):

> Return a linestring being a substring of the input one starting and ending at the given fractions of total 2d length. Second and third arguments are float8 values between 0 and 1.
>
> Return a linestring being a substring of the input one starting and ending at the given fractions of total 2d length. Second and third arguments are float8 values between 0 and 1. This only works with LINESTRINGs. To use with contiguous MULTILINESTRINGs use in conjunction with ST_LineMerge.

[image]

> A linestring seen with 1/3 midrange overlaid (0.333, 0.666)

Comment: Thanks for answers.Yes I know it but can you give an example code for that?

Comment: I've added a link to the documentation as well as the sample code they provided.

Comment: what you have added is a sample code and it will not work in spatialite.

Comment: I've removed the previous sample code, let me see if I can dig up something.